# Gson bug? Deserializer presence damages the process of serializing in Gson

Tags: java, serialization, gson

In an example below, I am trying to serialize my custom class `Couple`, which contains field of type `Point2D`.

I found, that the process of SErialzing depends on DEserializer presence.

Moreover, if deserializer is present, then the process of serializing works wrong.

How can desrializer affect reverse process and how can it damage it?

The class of `Point2DInstanceCreator` is not used.

```
package tests;

import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.InstanceCreator;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;


public class Try07_Point2D {

    static class Couple {
        Point2D p1, p2;

        public Couple() {
            p1 = new Point2D.Double();
            p2 = new Point2D.Double();
        }

        public Couple(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
            p1 = new Point2D.Double(x1, y1);
            p2 = new Point2D.Double(x2, y2);
        }

        void set(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
            p1.setLocation(x1, y1);
            p2.setLocation(x2, y2);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object object) {
            if( object instanceof Couple) {
                Couple ano = (Couple) object;
                return 
                        (p1 == null && ano.p1 == null || p1 != null && p1.equals(ano.p1)) &&
                        (p2 == null && ano.p2 == null || p2 != null && p2.equals(ano.p2));
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    static class Point2DInstanceCreator implements InstanceCreator<Point2D>{

        @Override
        public Point2D createInstance(Type type) {
            return new Point2D.Double();
        }

    }

    static class Point2DDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Point2D> {

        @Override
        public Point2D deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
                throws JsonParseException {

            Point2D.Double ans = new Point2D.Double();
            JsonObject obj = json.getAsJsonObject();

            ans.x = obj.get("x").getAsDouble();
            ans.y = obj.get("y").getAsDouble();

            return ans;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GsonBuilder gb;
        Gson gson0;

        gb = new GsonBuilder();

        gb = gb
         .enableComplexMapKeySerialization()
         .serializeNulls()
         .setPrettyPrinting()
         .setVersion(1.0)

    //     .registerTypeAdapter(Point2D.class, new Point2DInstanceCreator())
    //     .registerTypeAdapter(Point2D.class, new Point2DDeserializer())
         ;

        gson0 = gb.create();

        Couple value1;

        value1 = new Couple(12, 13, 14, 15);



        System.out.println("Version without deserializer:");
        System.out.println( gson0.toJson(value1) );

        gb = new GsonBuilder();

        gb = gb
         .enableComplexMapKeySerialization()
         .serializeNulls()
         .setPrettyPrinting()
         .setVersion(1.0)

//       .registerTypeAdapter(Point2D.class, new Point2DInstanceCreator())
         .registerTypeAdapter(Point2D.class, new Point2DDeserializer())
         ;

        gson0 = gb.create();



        System.out.println("Version with deserializer:");
        System.out.println( gson0.toJson(value1) );


    }

}
```

Output follows:

```
Version without deserializer:
{
  "p1": {
    "x": 12.0,
    "y": 13.0
  },
  "p2": {
    "x": 14.0,
    "y": 15.0
  }
}
Version with deserializer:
{
  "p1": {},
  "p2": {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems kind of like a bug in Gson. If you register a TypeAdaptor, it appears that it is getting used for both serialization and deserialization.

To fix this, have your Point2DDeserializer implement both JsonDeserializer and JsonSerializer:

```
static class Point2DDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Point2D>, JsonSerializer<Point2D> {

    @Override
    public Point2D deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {

        Point2D.Double ans = new Point2D.Double();
        JsonObject obj = json.getAsJsonObject();

        ans.x = obj.get("x").getAsDouble();
        ans.y = obj.get("y").getAsDouble();

        return ans;
    }

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(final Point2D point2D, final Type type, final JsonSerializationContext jsonSerializationContext) {
        return new Gson().toJsonTree(point2D);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's already an issue filed for this, https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=479&q=deserializer